# Google Workspace Add-ons: Building HTML interface possible?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

lately I am trying to figure out how to create an Google Workspace Add On that is able to show an iFrame. I started checking out the documentations of Google Apps Script and Google Add Ons.

So far I know, that I need to use the Card Service of Google to build Add ons. Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service

Actually, I just tried to figure out if any class or function of the Card Service can handle HTML Output or HTML file but ...

And so far I could figure out that you can build a bound script (only for Editor Add ons that is not in my interest) that is able to build HTML interfaces but I need this for standalone scripts that I can publish later as Add ons.

Also don't understand: Building a standalone script, why can I create HTML files when I am not able to use or display them?

After looong searching I would be glad if someone could enlight me ...

Comment: It's possible to have a Workspace addon that opens an Apps Script Web App, and the Web App can be published from the same GCP project as the addon.  An Apps Script Web App uses HTML Service.  Whether that has any value to you or not, depends on your needs.  The Web App can be published to run as the user, if you need that.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use CardService for Workspace Add-ons.

Only Editor add-ons (and Web Apps) allow for building custom interfaces with HTML/CSS and client-side javascript. Moreover, if User-Privacy and Anti-Trust laws/legislation keep gaining traction(GDPR, CCPA, etc.), there's a good chance we'll lose even that, but I digress.

If you're looking for official documentation on the matter, see [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions#_use_htmlcss_or_client-side_scripting)

Answer (score -1):

You can try making a web app on the same GCP project then add your web app link to a Card button that opens it up as an overlay

```js
var webAppOverlay = CardService.newOpenLink()
    .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
    .setUrl("Your web app link")

var textButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Web App")  
    .setOpenLink(webAppOverlay);

var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(textButton)
    .build();
```

Comment: Did anybody try this one out and can confirm it works to open a webpage?

Comment: I did, it works to open the web app in a popup window but will not allow you to open the web app inside the workspace add-on window.